# Getting previous score

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to find the clients whose scores changed from null to not null (e.g. 1,4,7). I used outer apply to get the most recent score which is null. My SQL is below and it is not right. Can you help me to fix it? Thanks!

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CLT_NBR,
t.SCORE
FROM TABLE_CLIENT t
OUTER APPLY
( SELECT TOP 1 t2.SCORE
  FROM TABLE_CLIENT t2
  WHERE t2.CLT_NBR= t.CLT_NBR AND t2.START_DT<t.START_DT
  ORDER BY t2.START_DT DESC
  ) AS sprev
 WHERE t.SCORE IS NOT NULL 
    AND sprev.SCORE IS NULL
```

Comment: That is the wrong approach to solving this problem (in general).  What database are you using and why do you need to use `outer apply`?

Comment: I use SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 2):

using `exists()`: (this will return rows if any previous score was `null`)

```
select distinct 
    clt_nbr
  , score
from table_client t
where score is not null
  and exists (
    select 1
    from table_client i
    where i.clt_nbr = t.clt_nbr 
      and i.start_dt < t.start_dt
      and i.score is null
      )
```

using `cross apply()`: (instead of `outer apply()` so we do not get rows where there was no previous row)

```
select 
    t.clt_nbr
  , t.score
from table_client t
  cross apply (
    select top 1 i.score
    from table_client i
    where i.clt_nbr = t.clt_nbr 
      and i.start_dt < t.start_dt
    order by i.start_dt desc
    ) as x
where t.score is not null 
  and x.score is null
```

using `lag()` (SQL Server 2012+): (returns rows where the most recent previous score is `null`)

```
with cte as (
    select  
        clt_nbr
      , score
      , start_dt
      , prev_score = lag(score) over (partition by clt_nbr order by start_dt)
      , prev_start_dt = lag(score) over (partition by clt_nbr order by start_dt)
    from table_client t
)
select 
    clt_nbr
  , score
from cte
where score is not null 
  and prev_score is null
  and prev_start_dt is not null
```

Comment: @Ice SqlZim took the time to provide 3 perfectly valid answers demonstrating some useful techniques.  You certainly can take a moment to ACCEPT the answer.  +1